# Monotone increasing proof

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that $\ln x$ is strictly monotone increasing.

I know the definition for monotone increasing, but not strictly monotone increasing, and don't understand where to start here.

Comment: Strictly monotone increasing means the inequality is strict. So x > y implies f(x) > f(y).

Comment: Ok, I understand now, but still don't know what I need to do to prove this formally

Comment: Using the definition Paul gave, it might be helpful to prove that any continuous function of a real variable on a convex set is a bijection if and only if it is strictly increasing (on whatever set it is defined on).  The inverse of $\ln x$ is $e^x$.  What does that tell us?

Comment: Well, I can see graphically that both ln x and $e^x$ are strictly increasing, but not sure why we need the inverse

Comment: @Hayden, did you mean to say any _continuous_ function?

Comment: @Nick, Yes, I did; thanks for the catch.  I'll edit that in.

Comment: The derivative is $\frac{1}{x}$, positive. Have you already proved that if derivative is positive in an interval, then the function is increasing in that interval?

Comment: Hmm, I believe I can use that. The second part of the question asks to prove that the limit is infinity because the harmonic series diverges, so i wonder if the harmonic series is relevant to the derivative proof

Comment: The harmonic series is not relevant to the derivative proof. But the derivative is relevant to the harmonic series comparison. For $\int_1^2 \frac{dx}{x}\ge \frac{1}{2}$, since on $[1,2]$ the function $\frac{1}{x}$ is $\ge \frac{1}{2}$. Similarly, $\int_2^3\frac{dx}{x}\ge \frac{1}{3}$, and so on.

Comment: So in order to prove that ln x -> inf as x-> inf, at which point would I use the harmonic summation, since I know it diverges? I understand the rationale for the case-by-case, but not sure how to tie it in to a summation

Comment: For $\ln x \to \infty$ use $\ln 2^{n} = n\ln 2$ and use that $\ln 2 > 0$.

Answer (score 4):

If we define the definition of ln $x$ by $\int_1^x\frac{1}{t}dt$ , where $x$ is positive ,

then ln $x$ is strictly increasing , since $\frac{1}{t}$ is positive in $(0,\infty)$

OR

Define ln $x$ by inverse function of exponential function. Then

ln $x$ is strictly increasing , since exponential function is strictly increasing.